# The difference in writing style between a book chapter and article in a journal

Tags: writing-style, books

My discipline is educational technology and I have been invited to submit a book chapter about integrating technology in my region. I published many articles in top refereed journals, but not sure whether the focus, style of writing and structure of articles are appropriate for book chapters.
Anyone can highlight the main differences?

Comment: I've edited to clarify that this question is about difference in writing style, not reputation (see [A book chapter in an edited volume vs an academic article. How do they compare?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/6133/a-book-chapter-in-an-edited-volume-vs-an-academic-article-how-do-they-compare) for the equivalent question about reputation).

Comment: Who is the target audience for the book chapter, compared to the target audience of your journal articles (the latter presumeably being "primarily researchers from your field")?

Comment: But what about the data analysis and results section, should it be the same as the article?

Answer (score 1):

You would want your chapter to fit into the whole project, whereas a journal article can usually stand alone.

Your chapter should not duplicate material in other chapters, although you may refer to material in another chapter.

You will want your chapter to be generally accessible.  For the specialized journal article, that doesn't matter so much.

The editor (could be more than one) may want to be rather more involved in choosing the content, organization, presentation, etc.,for a book project than for an isolated article.

To get a feel for the style desired, you could ask the editor(s) for one or more examples of the desired style.

Answer (score -1):

Also, importantly that book chapter does not have citation within the text, however, this is crucial in the review paper. In general, the audience of the book are interested but relatively new in the field, where the review paper audience are more specialised usually with previous knowledge and experience, so the writing style should take care of this.

Comment: "book chapter does not have citation within the text": There are plenty of books that have citations within the text.